# Xampp: How To Have Multiple Local Copies of the Same Site?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I know you can add multiple websites to xampp by just adding them to the httpd-vhosts.conf file. But how would you add the same exact same website twice to xampp?

Comment: you are talking about `htdocs`

Comment: Yes. I meant also adding the addition virtual host tags in the httpd-vhosts.conf file so it works.